# Does bind() change the function reference? | How to set permanently?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing event listener which was added with bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565471/removing-event-listener-which-was-added-with-bind)

I need to dynamically add and remove event listeners.  I also need to set the `this`.

Will this change the function reference?

```
element.addEventListener('click', funcA);
newFunc = funcA.bind(this);
element.removeEventListner('click', newFunc);
```

Will removeEventListener know that I want to remove funcA?

Or does it think I'm removing a new function all together?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Or does it think I'm removing a new function all together?

Yes, `.bind()` returns a new function object.

Comment: enter is a method in an object literal, and I always want `this` to point to the containing object.

Comment: Yes, you could do `this.enter = (function(){…}).bind(this)`, so that `this.enter` will reference the bound function only