# removeEventListener in bootstrapped addon not working when addon disabled

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I have noticed that after disabling a bootstrapped add-on, the `removeEventListener` does not seem to remove the listener and I can't work out the reason.

```
let contextMenu = window.document.getElementById('contentAreaContextMenu');
if (contextMenu) {
  contextMenu.addEventListener('popupshowing', 
            this.contextPopupShowing.bind(this), false);
  // added this to make sure they refer to the same function
  console.log(this.contextPopupShowing.toString()); 
}
```

And then on disabling the addon

```
console.log(this.contextPopupShowing.toString()); // same as above
this.contextMenu.removeEventListener('popupshowing', 
            this.contextPopupShowing.bind(this), false);
// just showing that 'this' is working
this.contextMenu.removeChild(this.menuitem);
```

Finally ...

```
contextPopupShowing: function() { 
  // logs even after removeEventListener
  console.log('contextPopupShowing called'); 
  // more code
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's `bind`'ed. What you gotta do is this:

When adding:

```
let contextMenu = window.document.getElementById('contentAreaContextMenu');
if (contextMenu) {
  this.contextPopupShowingBound = this.contextPopupShowing.bind(this);
  contextMenu.addEventListener('popupshowing', 
            this.contextPopupShowingBinded, false);
  // added this to make sure they refer to the same function
  console.log(this.contextPopupShowing.toString()); 
}
```

And then on disabling the addon

```
console.log(this.contextPopupShowing.toString()); // same as above
this.contextMenu.removeEventListener('popupshowing', 
            this.contextPopupShowingBound, false);
// just showing that 'this' is working
this.contextMenu.removeChild(this.menuitem);
```

Finally ...

```
contextPopupShowing: function() { 
  // logs even after removeEventListener
  console.log('contextPopupShowing called'); 
  // more code
},
```

You cannot use `bind` in the `removeEventListener`, I'm pretty sure.

See this excellent topic on the subject: [Removing event listener which was added with bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565471/removing-event-listener-which-was-added-with-bind/23403134)

Comment: Beat me to it. :p But I guess it's *bound*

Comment: Sucker!!!! Finally!! I woke up from my sleep this morning when and by chance logged in via mobile and saw the "how to intercept download", it was just posted 14min ago, so I even called the topic by making a comment that Im going to answer in a sec. I went to my desktop started it up, and by then you frikin posted! :'( And it was a MDN copy! :(

Comment: "But I guess it's bound" give me a break you're just pissed i beat you for once :nahnah: I used bind'ed so noobs more noob than me understand :P

Comment: I'm referring to your variable name and just tried to help :p

Comment: Aw god ok yah you got me.  i made up up that excuse on the "binded" easy for noobs to understand thing. :P edited as you got rid of fat arrows! :P

Comment: Thank you Noitidart & @nmaier I spent 2 hours wondering what was wrong. I didnt know that `bind` creates a new function. I have used it with a few eventlisteners. I need to rethink my approach. :)