# Class function re-running inside function constantly

Tags: javascript

```
class AddSlider {
  constructor(elem, dir){
    this.elem = elem;
    this.dir = dir;
    this.slider = document.getElementsByClassName(this.elem)[0];
    this.sliderHandle = document.createElement('div');
  }

  /*Add handle to element and add styles depending on direction slider is needed to go*/
  build() {
    this.sliderHandle.classList.add('slider__handle');

    if (this.dir === 'right') {
      this.sliderHandle.style.right = 0;
      this.sliderHandle.style.top = 0;
      this.sliderHandle.style.width = '10px';
      this.sliderHandle.style.height = '100%';
    }
    if (this.dir === 'bottom') {
      this.sliderHandle.style.bottom = 0;
      this.sliderHandle.style.width = '100%';
      this.sliderHandle.style.height = '10px';
    }

    this.slider.appendChild(this.sliderHandle);
  }

  /*Add dragging class for styles when dragging, do resize sum and add it live as inline style*/
  Resize(e) {
    let cont = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-container')[0];

    this.slider.classList.add('dragging');
    this.sliderHandle.classList.add('dragging');

    if(this.dir === 'right') {
      this.slider.style.maxWidth = cont.offsetWidth + 'px';
      this.slider.style.width = (e.clientX - this.slider.offsetLeft) + 'px'; 
    }

    if(this.dir === 'bottom') {
      this.slider.style.maxHeight = '500px';
      this.slider.style.height = (e.clientY - this.slider.offsetTop) + 'px';
    }
  }

  /*Add events listeners when moving mouse and mouse up to window*/
  initResize() {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.Resize.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopResize.bind(this));
  }

  /*Remove event listeners and classes*/
  stopResize() {
    console.log('STOPPED!!!');
    this.slider.classList.remove('dragging');
    this.sliderHandle.classList.remove('dragging');
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.Resize);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.stopResize);
  }

  /*init*/
  init() {
    this.build();
    this.sliderHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', this.initResize.bind(this));
  }

}

let componentSlider = new AddSlider('slider', 'bottom');
componentSlider.init();
```

Does anybody know why the resize function is running at all times and the stopResize function is not permanently removing classes and window listeners? The stopResize function does console log the text and remove classes but the classes are added back straight away and the slider is not stopping from moving.

Comment: `.bind()` returns a new function instance, so `removeEventListener` will not work

Comment: any work arounds?

Comment: You may either save a link to the function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22870717/7746496 or avoid using `.bind()`. `this` may be passed in a closure.