# Remove Click handler from fabric dialog overlay

Tags: javascript, office-ui-fabric, office-fabric

I'm using [Office-Fabric-Ui](https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/Dialog/Dialog.html) and its dialog functionality.

```
 var template = $("<div id='something'>This is modal dialog content</div>");
 var uidialog = new fabric["Dialog"](template[0]);
```

Now, `uidialog` has `_overlay` variable, on click of this `_overlay` the `uidialog` closes, but we don't want the dialog to close on click and trying to remove the handlers on `_overlay`

I have tried many solutions some of them are but still unable to remove the handlers from overlay element:

*Solution 1*

```
fabric.Dialog.prototype.RemoveOverlayClick = function () {
    this._overlay.overlayElement.removeEventListener("click", this.close.bind(this));
    this._overlay.overlayElement.removeEventListener("click", this._overlay.hide.bind(this._overlay));
    this._overlay.overlayElement.removeEventListener("click", this.__proto__.close.bind(this.__proto__));
    this._overlay.overlayElement.removeEventListener("click", fabric.Dialog.prototype.close.bind(fabric.Dialog.prototype));
}
uidialog.RemoveOverlayClick();
```

*Solution 2*

```
uidialog._overlay.overlayElement.removeEventListener("click", uidialog.__proto__.close.bind(this.__proto__));
uidialog._overlay.overlayElement.removeEventListener("click", fabric.Dialog.prototype.close.bind(fabric.Dialog.prototype));
```

Can anybody suggest how to remove click event handlers on `fabric.Overlay`?

Answer (score 1):

I was not successful in `removeEventHandler` for click, but I used [cloneNode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp) so that the Dialog will not close on click of overlay.

```
var _dialogOverlay = uidialog._overlay.overlayElement.cloneNode();
document.body.appendChild(_dialogOverlay);
uidialog._overlay.overlayElement.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case `cloneNode` might not be the best way forward. The problem is that `bind` actually returns a new function. The only way to remove eventhandlers is to know the function reference.

For our recent project we overwrote the `addEventListener` function globally (in the top of the document, or at least before the handler we are interested in is added) evertime an event is added we save a reference for it.

Basically we extend the `EventTarget` object with two new functions and overwrite one.

```
        <script>
            (function () {
                "use strict";

                var f = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;

                EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function (type, fn, capture) {
                    this.f = f;
                    this._eventHandlers = this._eventHandlers || {};
                    this._eventHandlers[type] = this._eventHandlers[type] || [];
                    this._eventHandlers[type].push([fn, capture]);
                    this.f(type, fn, capture);
                }

                EventTarget.prototype.removeAllEventListeners = function (type) {
                    this._eventHandlers = this._eventHandlers || {};
                    if (type in this._eventHandlers) {
                        var eventHandlers = this._eventHandlers[type];
                        for (var i = eventHandlers.length; i--;) {
                            var handler = eventHandlers[i];
                            this.removeEventListener(type, handler[0], handler[1]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                EventTarget.prototype.getAllEventListeners = function (type) {
                    this._eventHandlers = this._eventHandlers || {};
                    this._eventHandlers[type] = this._eventHandlers[type] || [];
                    return this._eventHandlers[type];
                }

            })();
        </script>
```