# addEventListener with named function and parameters

Tags: javascript

I know there are lots of similar questions out there but somehow
I did not find anything for this problem - can you point me in the right direction

Let's say we have a function

```
window.logMeThis = function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}
```

then I need to add an event listener

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', window.logMeThis.bind(null, "something"));
```

which looks good at first - but .bind creates a new fn

and now I can't remove the listener

```
window.removeEventListener('keypress', window.logMeThis);
```

Comment: there is no other magic way. you either store reference to new 'bound' version or you are unable to detach listener.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing event listener which was added with bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565471/removing-event-listener-which-was-added-with-bind)

Comment: @Teemu yes, this question is the one, thanks guys

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why to bind an event listener to `null`? If `this` is used in the handler, that would fire an error. Or is that only a simplified example?

Comment: absolutely simplified version, and this was copy pasted

Comment: @skyboyer that's not strictly true if you use the `once` option since then the listener is removed once invoked

Comment: @CervEd right, but in this case you would nether need to remove event listener manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that:

```
window.logMeThis = function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}
var myFunc = window.logMeThis.bind(null, "something");
window.addEventListener('keypress', myFunc);
```

To remove the listener, just do that:

```
window.removeEventListener('keypress', myFunc);
```

Basically, you need to have a reference of your function to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to bind the function to a specific context then you can do this:

```
var boundFunction = window.logMeThis.bind(null, "something");
window.addEventListener('keypress', boundFunction);
```

Now you have a reference to the function to remove it.

Comment: and what if I don't have to use the bind ?

Comment: then this: window.addEventListener('keypress', window.logMeThis);

Answer (score 0):

You're right:

> This method creates a function whose body is similar to the function
>   on which it is called

just pass the existing function instead and you will be able to reference it like so:

```
var i = 0;
    window.logMeThis = function(msg){
        console.log(msg+''+i);

      i++;
    }
    window.addEventListener('keypress', window.logMeThis, false);
    window.removeEventListener('keypress', window.logMeThis, false);
```

Comment: I afraid of this: window.logMeThis('hello') invokes the function - once

Comment: You're right - need to pass a function instead of executing it.