# Custom Element class with a reusable event handler method

Tags: javascript, closures, custom-element

I have a custom button using this Custom Element class:

```
class Button extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.reusableClickHandler)
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.reusableClickHandler)
    }

    reusableClickHandler() {
        console.log(this) // how to get `this` to equal the button instance
    }
}
```

The custom button listens for clicks on `document`, and removes the stale event handlers when the button is removed from the DOM.

Is it possible for me to keep `this` within `reusableClickHandler()` equal to the button instance? I'm not sure how to write it.

Also I know that a button created this way is not optimal, it's just to demonstrate the problem. Thanks

Comment: Try `document.addEventListener('click', this.reusableClickHandler.bind(this))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a specific `this` reference in callbacks, you can bind the callback with the desired object.

```
document.addEventListener('click', this.reusableClickHandler.bind(this));
```

Just a side note, `bind` returns a new function and if there is a requirement to remove the event listener then you might want to store the bound function in a class variable(maybe in the constructor) and use the class property to add and remove the event listener.

Comment: Another pattern is to keep the ``addEventListener`` and ``removeEventListener`` in the same scope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921027/remove-event-listener-that-has-been-added-using-bindthis/54945857#54945857

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Nice way of handling add/remove.

Comment: Whenyou have multiple handlers, add an array: ``this.handlers.push(listen(...))`` then in the ``disconnectedCallback`` all you need is: ``this.handlers.forEach(removeFunc=> removeFunc())``