# Add and remove eventListeners with callback function and arguments

Tags: javascript

I have a navigation with multiple event listeners: `click` and `hover`. This event listeners can change, e.g. on browser resize. I add the event listeners in my own method which gets called if listeners should be re-initialized. My problem in my following class: `removeEventListener` does not work. So re-initialization causes that both `click` and `hover` fires.

```js
class Navigation {
 constructor(element) {
  this.element = element;
  this.changeButton = this.element.querySelector("button");
  this.version = "hover";
  this.navItemElements = Array.from(this.element.querySelectorAll(".nav-item"));
  this.navItems = this.createNavItems(this.navItemElements);
  this.clickHandler = (event) => this.navItemHoverHandler(event);
  this.changeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
   this.isHoverVersion = !(this.isHoverVersion);
   console.log("Change trigger. Is hover version --> " + this.isHoverVersion);
   this.initListeners();
  });
  this.clickHandler = (event, navItem) => this.navItemClickHandler(event, navItem);
  this.hoverHandler = (event, navItem) => this.navItemHoverHandler(event, navItem);
  this.initListeners();
 }

 initListeners() {

  console.log("Init listeners");
  console.log(this.navItems);

  if (this.isHoverVersion) {
   this.navItems.forEach((navItem) => {
    console.log(navItem);
    navItem.link.addEventListener('mouseover', e => this.hoverHandler(e, navItem));
    navItem.link.addEventListener('mouseout', e => this.hoverHandler(e, navItem));
    navItem.link.removeEventListener('click',this.clickHandler);
   })
  } else {
   this.navItems.forEach((navItem) => {
    navItem.link.addEventListener('click', e => this.clickHandler(e, navItem));
    navItem.link.removeEventListener('mouseover', this.hoverHandler);
    navItem.link.removeEventListener('mouseout', this.hoverHandler);
   })
  }
 }

 navItemClickHandler(event, navItem) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Click handler executed');
  console.log(navItem);
 }

 navItemHoverHandler(event, navItem) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Hover handler executed');
  console.log(navItem);
 }

 createNavItems(navItemElements) {
  let navItems = [];
  navItemElements.forEach((itemElement) => {
   navItems.push(this.createNavItemObject(itemElement));
  });
  return navItems;
 }

 createNavItemObject(navItem) {
  let container = navItem;
  let link = navItem.querySelector("a");
  return  {
   container: container,
   link: link,
  };
 }
}

let navigationElement = document.querySelector(".navigation");

new Navigation(navigationElement);
```

```css
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <button id="changeButton">Change trigger</button>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="">Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`navItem` is an object, which I created before. `navItem.link` is the HTML Anchor Element.

**Question:**

How can I bind the listener to the specific object? 
I need to call the same method, but with its specific `navItem` object...

**Update:**

Added working code example.
The navigation gets initialized with click trigger. Clicking the button will toggle click / hover. In this example, after toggling from click to hover, both listeners get executed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess, bind() is not possible in combination of arrow functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the exact function you used in `addEventListener`, check the [explanation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#Matching_event_listeners_for_removal).

So in your example you define a new anonymous function:

```js
navItem.link.addEventListener('mouseout', e =>
    this.hoverHandler(e, navItem)
);
```

The arrow function is the new anonymous function: `e => ...`. So instead using this anonymous function you need to use the exact same function.

To get the `navItem` in the event handler you can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). The first argument of bind defines the context (`this`) in the event handler and all other arguments are preceding any provided (in this case the `event` argument). But you should note that `bind()` creates a new [function reference every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565471/removing-event-listener-which-was-added-with-bind), so you need to save the reference for the removing. One way to achieve this could be to save the function on the `navItem`. For the `hover` events it would be:

```js
if (this.isHoverVersion) {
    this.navItems.forEach(navItem => {
        // save function
        navItem.hoverHandler = this.navItemHoverHandler.bind(null, navItem);

        navItem.link.addEventListener('mouseover', navItem.hoverHandler);
        navItem.link.addEventListener('mouseout', navItem.hoverHandler);
    });
} else {
    this.navItems.forEach(navItem => {
        navItem.link.removeEventListener('mouseover', navItem.hoverHandler);
        navItem.link.removeEventListener('mouseout', navItem.hoverHandler);
    });
}
```

Additionally you need to change your `navItemHoverHandler` to this:

```js
navItemHoverHandler(navItem, event) { // reversed order
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Hover handler executed');
    console.log(navItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this does not help for my purpose. currentTarget is the HTML element, which as fired the event. But I need to pass an object to the handler (navItem). So what I need to do: pass a local argument...

Comment: Ahh okay, then the solution depends on your code. Can you add a running code snippet, as @jsduniya has already suggested?